Add resonances to monopole antenna
How can I design a "simple" low frequency monopole antenna with multiple resonating frequencies?
I elaborate...
I need to design a sort of monopole antenna with multiple resonating frequencies starting from 1 MHz to 100 MHz, with a resonance every 10 MHz.
If I just draw a basic monopole, the wavelength at 1 MHz is 300 m...So the monopole should be long 300/4 to resonate at 1 MHz. Then I have resonances every lambda/2.
First problem: default monopole is too long for its installation...How to solve it?
Then, how can I add multiple resonances? The first thing I can try is to split the single monopole into multiple pieces of monopoles, in line along its length and add a sort of RLC circuit between each monopole in order to "close" the circuit and enlong the antenna. But how can I design such network?
To give an idea...

Otherwise the simplest approach could be design multiple stand alone monopoles each one resonating at the frequency of interest and place them close to each other (very close) and share their feeding. This is a bulky design but surely working.
I'd like to do a nice single antenna tho and I'd like to have a single feeding point. Not multiple antennas if it is possible.

This type of antenna exists with an "intermediate" inductor. The "discone" antennas with a large bandwidth also exist. But at 1 MHz, it could be a problem ... NB: most begin at 25-30 MHz.

Try explaining the problem rather than proposing a solution to an unknown problem.

This sounds similar to what amateur radio operators do with trap antennas. Parallel resonant circuits are used between antenna sections to make the antenna look shorter at higher frequencies.
Let's say for instance you want an antenna to be resonant at 10 MHz and 30 MHz, a quarter wavelength at 10 MHz is 30 meters, at 30 MHz it's 10 meters. So you make the antenna element 30 meters long, but at 10 meters from the feedpoint you put a trap, a parallel LC circuit, resonant at 30 MHz. You now have a 20 meter section and a 10 meter section of antenna.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A parallel LC circuit will present a high impedance at it's resonant frequency, and a low impedance at other frequencies. So it blocks the 30 MHz signal from reaching the 20 meter long section, to the 30 MHz signal it looks like the antenna is only 10 meters long. the trap lets through the 10 MHz signal, so at that frequency the antenna looks like it's 30 meters long.
The traps could be discrete inductors and capacitors, but often they are made out of coaxial cable wrapped around a cylindrical form.
This is usually only done with a few frequency bands, so it's hard to say how well it would work in your situation. 1 MHz is problematic, an antenna for that frequency, and indeed up into the tens of Megahertz, are usually made with loading coils or other techniques to shorten them. You also have to take into account the bandwidth of the traps, how narrow will they need to be? You might get some overlap at the higher frequencies.
Another option may be to us a non-resonant antenna such as a long wire and use a tuner to adjust it. Again you're asking for a very broad range of frequencies so it's hard to say what's going to work best, or if anything will work well at all.
